# How to update an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

For example,

```
{
  id:"monday",
  names:[
    {one:"white", two:"pink"},
    {uno:"blanco", dos:"rosado"}
  ]
}
```

How would you change `white` to `black`?
So far, I've got this:

```
r.db.table.get('monday').update({
  names: r.row("names").nth(0)
})
```

Which specifies the 0th index of `names`, but not sure how to further specify the `one` field and then change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far is pretty correct but you replace `names` with its first sub-object (I guess you saw that result already).

You just need to use a `merge` to alter the sub-object, and a `changeAt` on `names` to put the altered sub-object in the array, just like this:

```
r.db.table.get('monday').update({
  names: r.row('names').changeAt(0, r.row('names').nth(0).merge({one: 'black'}))
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But jeezuz, to update one little thing, you gotta specify (in this case) 'names' 3 times and the 1st index twice....that's.....wow

Comment: It's indeed very long to write, but the thing is it's "generic" writings and most of all it's a fast DB! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your data is stored in an object with the name of `obj`; something like

```
var obj = {...}
```

you can make this work:

```
obj.names[0].one = "black";
```

I have actually tried it using firebug no issues.
Each element in the array is independent so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

First off all, you should use `replace` instead of `update`.

1. Get record without `names` field.
2. `merge` it with  new `names` (remove 1st element from it, add at the 1st position new element in which we replaced `white` to `black` in `one` field)

Something like this:

```
   r.db.table.get('monday').replace(function(doc){
      return doc.without({names:  true}). merge({
        names: doc("names").deleteAt(0).prepend(doc("names").nth(0).merge({
          one : "black" 
        }))
      })
    })
```

Comment: Why `replace` in favor of `update`? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40071655/1543640) seems more straightforward?

Comment: @House3272 yeh, I forgot about `changeAt` =\

Comment: Thanks anyways! Btw, in your answer, is `.get().get()` intentional?

Comment: @House3272 no, typo )